# query with linq compiled

Tags: .net, sql, vb.net, linq

Hi I just discoverd that my web application is slow probably because of linq.

I'm sort of lost with those compiled queries, can you help me to compile a query and still make it usable to query the query? (is that understandable? :p)
For instance this query(in vb.net):

```
 Dim query = (From p In db.ProductCategories _
               Group Join t In db.Translate_ProductCategories On p.ID_Category Equals t.Category_ID Into res = Group From r1 In res.DefaultIfEmpty _
               Where r1.Language_ID = langID And p.CategoryActive = True _
               Select New With {.name = r1.Name, .idcat = p.ID_Category, .level = p.CategoryLevel, .index = p.CategoryIndex, .parentID = p.CategoryParent_ID})
```

Then I want to be sure to still be able to do such things:

```
Dim level0 = (From l In query Where l.level = 0 Order By l.index Ascending Select l)
```

Thanks for the help

Edit:

I tried doing that:

```
Dim myquery = CompiledQuery.Compile( _
    Function(db As EshopDataContext) _
      (From p In db.ProductCategories _
               Group Join t In db.Translate_ProductCategories On p.ID_Category Equals t.Category_ID Into res = Group From r1 In res.DefaultIfEmpty _
               Where r1.Language_ID = langID And p.CategoryActive = True _
               Select New With {.name = r1.Name, .idcat = p.ID_Category, .level = p.CategoryLevel, .index = p.CategoryIndex, .parentID = p.CategoryParent_ID}))

Dim query = myquery.Invoke(db)

Dim level0 = (From l In query Where l.level = 0 Order By l.index Ascending Select l)
```

and I have error "The query results cannot be enumerated more than once." on this line

```
cptCat1 = level1.Where(Function(l1) l1.parentID = parentId1).Count
```

Comment: what makes you think it's slow because of linq?  What is the source of your data (DB, object collection, other?)

Comment: because of this: http://peterkellner.net/2009/05/06/linq-to-sql-slow-performance-compilequery-critical/  :)

Comment: Did you try the syntax in that article to compile?  And you cannot conclude you query is slow because of compiled query until you compile and compare. Is this a query you need to execute many times - if not compiling won't help. Use log to get the TSQL from you LINQ and display the estimated execution plan in SSMS.

Comment: Well yes I tried, but then I can't go further because it says :: The query results cannot be enumerated more than once.

Comment: Please always post the code that is throwing the error and the error message.

Comment: Are you using MSSQL?  If so open up a profiler session and see what's executing, copy/paste that into SSMS and turn on display actual execution, that will tell you if the tables used need additional indexing or not.

Comment: Try a strait ToList like in the link (not the From l In query Where l.level = 0 Order By l.index Ascending Select l)

Comment: You can't extend a compiled query with more expressions as this negates the compile time optimization. You should stick the variable into a static field so that the compilation only occurs once as well. It may be best to create a different compiled query with the additional filters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this first:
http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/03/compiled-or-bust.html

here is How-To from MS on Compiled queries if you really think you have to after reading that.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399335.aspx#Y0 (for linq2sql)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896297.aspx#Y300 (for linq2EF)